# How to use Vyper to call PancakeSwap contract

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap, vyper

I'm writing a Vyper contract to call the `swapExactTokensForTokens` function of PancakeSwap, but when I try to deploy, I find it doesn't work. I don't know what happened. I really need help.

This is my contract:

```
# @version ^0.2

from vyper.interfaces import ERC20

interface PancakeRouter:
    def swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountIn: uint256,
        amountOutMin: uint256,
        path: address[3],
        to: address,
        deadline: uint256
    ) -> uint256[3]: nonpayable

PANCAKESWAP: constant(address) = 0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E
WBNB: constant(address) = 0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c

@external
def swap(tokenIn: address, tokenOut: address, amountIn: uint256):
    ERC20(tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, self, amountIn)
    ERC20(tokenIn).approve(PANCAKESWAP, amountIn)

    res: Bytes[128] = raw_call(
        PANCAKESWAP,
        concat(
            method_id("swapExactTokensForTokens(uint256, uint256, address[], address, uint256)"),
            convert(amountIn, bytes32),
            convert(0, bytes32),
            convert(160, bytes32),
            convert(self, bytes32),
            convert(block.timestamp, bytes32),
            convert(3, bytes32),
            convert(tokenIn, bytes32),
            convert(WBNB, bytes32),
            convert(tokenOut, bytes32),
        ),
        max_outsize=128,
    )
```

Comment: Please explain exactly what doesn't work, the deployment? Transaction you fire fails? Add as many details as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You're using [this example code](https://github.com/t4sk/vyper-by-example/blob/master/src/Uniswap.vy) only changed Uniswap to Pancakeswap and WETH to WBNB. The code is otherwise the same, so that's not a contract code issue.

You probably haven't pre-approved `tokenIn` to allow `PANCAKESWAP` to spend your tokens, so it fails at

```
ERC20(tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, self, amountIn)
```

Also make sure you're running on BSC blockchain and not Ethereum.